# How the error of Least Squares changes with changing the approximation function?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, least-squares, numerical-optimization

I am doing an exercice where I have to put the normal equation of a least squares problem, in the form: $C\alpha = d$

The given points are the following: $(-2,2), (2,4), (3,6)$
And the approximation function is this one:

$$f(x) = \alpha_1 x + \alpha_2 x^2$$

My solution is the following one:

$$
     \left[
     \begin{array}{cc|c}
       17&27&22\\
       27&113&70
     \end{array}
     \right] 
$$
with $C$ the $(2x2)$ matrix and $d = $${22}\choose{70}$$ t$ (sorry for my weak $\LaTeX$ knowlegde)

So first question: Is my solution right?

Second, it is asked after that to tell WITHOUT CALCULATIONS how the error of the solution would change, if we change the approximation function to:

$$g(x) = \alpha_1x + \alpha_2x^2 + \alpha_3x^4$$

How to do that without calculation? What would be a right answer to this?

PS: I would have calculated again the $C\alpha=d$ and checked the condition number of the new $C$ and compared it to the condition number of the previous $C$ and would have said that the new one is ill-conditioned. But we have to answer without calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your first question: Almost, but I get $(-2)^2\cdot2+2^2\cdot4+3^2\cdot6=78$ where you have $70$.

On your second question: You now have three functions to approximate three values. You can readily check that the three vectors of their values at the three points $2$, $-2$, $3$ are linearly independent: $(-2,2,3)$, $(4,4,9)$ and $(16,16,81)$. Thus the approximation error will be zero.

Comment: 1) Thanks for your answer. 2) Could you please tell me, if my solution above (the first part of my question) is right? For C*(alpha)=d    and 3) Could you please write down the vectors that you mean? Thanks in advance

Comment: @ZelelB: Sorry, I'd forgotten to answer your first question. I've updated the answer.

Comment: 1) Oh, you're right for 78! Calculation error! Thx! 2) You're right, I see! And if they were not (let's say in another example), would have been another fact about the error that one could tell without calculations, when the approximation function changes to one with a higher order? (for ex. here g(x) vs f(x): 4th order (x^4) vs 2nd order (x^2)?

Comment: @ZelelB: If the vectors were linearly dependent, that would mean that you can't do any better than before, since they span the same space as before; so in that case the approximation error would stay the same. If the previous approximation was lacking only one dimension, then these are the only two options, the error can go to zero or stay the same. If the previous approximation was lacking more than one dimension, there's also the option in between of improving the error. (Of course the error can never get worse when you add another function, since its coefficient can be chosen to be zero.)

Comment: Okay! Great! Thanks for the help!